# How to decrease value of variable over time

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and am creating a pet simulator. I want the hunger and sleep variable of the pet to decrease by 1 over time. So perhaps each variable decreases by 1 every 5 minutes while the user is in the program.

```
class pet(object):
    age: 0
    excitement_reduce = 3
    excitement_max = 10
    excitement_warning = 3
    food_reduce = 2
    food_max = 10
    food_warning = 2
    level: 0
    sleep_reduce = 1
    sleep_max = 10
    vocab = [""]

    def __init__(self, name, pet_type):
        self.age = self.age
        self.excitement = randrange(self.excitement_max)
        self.food = randrange(self.food_max)
        self.level = self.level
        self.name = self.name
        self.pet_type = self.pet_type
        self.sleep = randrange(self.sleep_max)
        self.vocab = self.vocab[:]

    def __clock_tick(self):
        self.food -= 1
        self.sleep -= 1
```

I thought perhaps I could create another function of `__clock_tick`? Or maybe I import the python `time` module into my code.

Comment: I wouldn't add some clock/schedule logic to the `Pet` class.
Instead I would create a `Simulator` class that masters the clock and updates the `Pet` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Timer object to call your `__clock_tick` on a periodic basis.

```
import threading
...

PERIOD_SEC = 5 * 60

# in your constructor
def __init__(self):
    self.timer_task = None

def __clock_tick(self):
    self.food -= 1
    self.sleep -= 1

    # timers are one shot, so you need to start a new one as long as
    # you want to execute this callback on a periodic basis
    self.make_alive()

# to start your timer
def make_alive(self):
    self.timer_task = threading.Timer(PERIOD_SEC, self.__clock_tick, args=(self,))
    self.timer_task.start()

# to stop your timer
def kill(self):
    if (self.timer_task is not None):
        self.timer_task.cancel()
        self.timer_task = None
```

NOTE: By convention, a function name which starts with two underscore is private and cannot be seen to child class which inherits from your main class. You may rather want it to be protected instead (i.e.: one single underscore).

NOTE: the advantage of using a Timer over basic busy waiting loops is that you reduce the  CPU usage, benefits from sync mechanisms provided by the `threading` API and keep your program running without blocking it.

Comment: @DevTuck You're welcome! Keep in mind to mark as answer to help others in the future :)

Comment: Thank you - got it! Learning my way around stack overflow too XD

Answer (score 0):

##### You can use the [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) module with a loop to call `__clock_tick` method every 5 minutes (300 seconds) as follows:

```
from random import randrange
import time

class pet(object):
    age: 0
    excitement_reduce = 3
    excitement_max = 10
    excitement_warning = 3
    food_reduce = 2
    food_max = 10
    food_warning = 2
    level: 0
    sleep_reduce = 1
    sleep_max = 10
    vocab = [""]

    def __init__(self, name, pet_type):
        # set self values
        self.age = 0
        self.excitement = randrange(self.excitement_max)
        self.food = randrange(self.food_max)
        self.level = 0
        self.name = name
        self.pet_type = pet_type
        self.sleep = randrange(self.sleep_max)
        self.vocab = self.vocab[:]
        


    def __clock_tick(self):
        self.food -= 1
        self.sleep -= 1
        print('Clock tick called')
        print(self.food , self.sleep)

    
    def callClockTick(self):
        while True:
            self.__clock_tick()
            time.sleep(300)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = pet('abc', 'cat')
    p.callClockTick()
```

Here I added the `print` method for visualization purposes.

**Note: I have slightly modified the class `pet`'s variable declarations in this example. But the idea will work regardless of it.**

Comment: Hi what does the bottom part do? if __name__ == "__main__": and where would this go in my code?

Comment: It's boilerplate code that protects users from accidentally invoking the script when they didn't intend to. For details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do